# Replace letters in list of txt files - powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi I'm trying to change the letters in various files (which I have in listed in a text file) I can go through the files individually using the command below, but I was wondering if there's a way to loop through the list amending each of the file contents.

example I'd like to change test-pop-test to test-bar-test and this is the content of several files, not the name of the file.

The code I am using is below, amending the names before running.

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\list.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "pop", "bar" } | Set-Content c:\temp\test2.txt
```

Each object is  a text file that I would like it to loop through, so list.txt contains a list of text files where the contents are to be amended, not sure if I explained this very well.. :)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic example:

```
$Temp = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp -Force

ForEach ($f in $Temp)
{
    (Get-Content $f) |
      % { $_ -replace 'pop', 'bar' } |
      Set-Content $f
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, don't know why I didn't see that.. Thanks for your help, thankfully its not going to be another ridiculously late night again :)